# cxf webclient fails to contact openAM with internal errors

Tags: java, ssl, openam, cxf-client, web-client

Am trying to contact openAM by using the cxf webclient. When i create the webclient object and call the openAM's authenticate rest API with username and password, it returns status as 500. Is this due to ssl certificate problem? If so how could i solve it?

Comment: a 500er error can not be related to SSL issue as this would be on a different protocol layer

Answer (score 0):

Prasana,

Many things can go wrong but we are going to need more information to point you in the right direction.

First, take a look at the error message that OpenAM sends to the client, if any.

If that doesn't help you can always take a look at the OpenAM's debug files (specially one that's called "Authentication") which should be located in "$OPENAM_CONFIG_DIR/$OPENAM_DEPLOYMENT_URI/debug".

Finally, there might some information on the application container's log files as well.

Hope this helps you troubleshoot the issue.